# Transform CSV to JSON with Apache NiFi ExecuteStreamCommand - Python

Tags: python, json, csv, apache-nifi

I am currently having an issue with the Apache NiFi processor ExecuteStreamCommand and the implementation of a Python-script.

I wrote the code below to  transform 50 different csv-files into json. Afterwards I'am going to write those JSON to HDFS.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'***.csv',
                 sep='\t',
                 skiprows=2)

df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
del df['Charge']
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: "Zeitstempel", df.columns[1]: "Maschine"})
df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)

df['zeitstempel'] = pd.to_datetime(df['zeitstempel'], format='%d.%m.%y, %X')
df['zeitstempel'] = df['zeitstempel'].astype(str)
columns = list(df.columns)

for column in range(len(columns)):
    if str(columns[column]).startswith('_'):
        columns[column] = columns[column][1:]

df.columns = columns

machine = df["maschine"][0]
day = str(df["zeitstempel"][0])[5:7]
month = str(df["zeitstempel"][0])[8:10]
year = str(df["zeitstempel"][0])[0:4]
fileName = machine + "_" + year + "_" + month + "_" + day + ".json"
filePath = "***" + fileName

df.to_json(filePath, orient='records', date_format='iso', date_unit='s', lines=True)
```

The script works fine on my local directory, but how do I need to change the input and output for NiFi?

The NiFi-flow is as follow: ListFile > FetchFile > ExecuteStreamCommand > PutHDFS.

I tried the code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin,
                 sep='\t',
                 skiprows=2)

df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
del df['Charge']
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: "Zeitstempel", df.columns[1]: "Maschine"})
df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)

df['zeitstempel'] = pd.to_datetime(df['zeitstempel'], format='%d.%m.%y, %X')
df['zeitstempel'] = df['zeitstempel'].astype(str)
columns = list(df.columns)

for column in range(len(columns)):
    if str(columns[column]).startswith('_'):
        columns[column] = columns[column][1:]

df.columns = columns

machine = df["maschine"][0]
day = str(df["zeitstempel"][0])[5:7]
month = str(df["zeitstempel"][0])[8:10]
year = str(df["zeitstempel"][0])[0:4]
fileName = machine + "_" + year + "_" + month + "_" + day + ".json"

df.to_json(sys.stdout, orient='records', date_format='iso', date_unit='s', lines=True)
```

And configured the processor like:

[image: ExecuteStreamCommand configuration]

Thank you in advance from Germany!

Nicko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor something like this way -

[image]

Also please check the official docs - [ExecuteStreamCommand](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html)

Comment: Thanks @Vikramsinh Shine. This works works fine for the first problem I had. Now I had to figure out how to customize my script to work the way I want'em to.

Comment: If this helps to solve the asked problem, then please accept the answer, thanks!